# 10:36:31+1000 why is this value been converted to this 06:06:31+05:30 when I am using moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

`10:36:31+1000` Why is this value been converted to this `06:06:31+05:30` when I am using moment js.
This is the time I am getting from the back-end `10:36:31+1000`

This is the function that I am using
 `{moment(value).format('hh:mm:ss')}`

Expected output - 10:36:31
but I am getting - 06:06:31